# Java PriorityBlockingQueue FIFOEntry sequence number limit

Tags: java, collections

According to the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html), PriorityBlockingQueue doesn't guarantee about the ordering of elements with equal priority. They suggest to use a secondary key (sequenceNumber) to enforce a specific ordering (e.g. FIFO).

An `AtomicLong` is used as a secondary key in the given FIFOEntry example at this page. However, limit of this secondary key doesn't considered at this code. It seems that if we continue to call `getAndIncrement()`, when the long limit exceeds, FIFO behavior is corrupted.

What can we do against such an overflow without preventing application flow? For example, stop processing on queue and update all sequence numbers and reset seqNum to 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any idea how large a 64-bit number is? You'll be long dead before you run out of long values.

`9,223,372,036,854,775,807` is the biggest value for a signed long, if you imagine using one million numbers per second, you'll have enough numbers for about `292471` years.